# Why is code skipping over for loop in integer length program

Tags: java

Im trying to create a program to find the length of a given number. I thought i would do this by taking the number and dividing by 10 and then checking to see if the number was <= 0. I dident want to edit the global number so i created a instance version of the number and used that as the condition in the for loop.

So obviously this dident work so naturally i ended up looking in the debugger to figure out what was going on. It looks as if the program is completely skipping over the for loop any help would be appreciated.

```
public static void sumFirstAndLastDigit(int number) {
        int numberLength = 0;
        int instanceNumber = number;
        for(int i = 0; instanceNumber <= 0; i++) {
            instanceNumber /= 10;
            numberLength = i;   
        }
        System.out.println("Number length = " + numberLength);
        // to find length of number loop division by 10
    }
}
```

The program should use the for loop to keep dividing by 10 until the number is = to or less than than zero and for how many times the loop ran should be stored in the number length integer. In this case with the number 12321 the answer should be 6 but it prints 0.

Comment: @Avinash Gupta wrote the only correct answer for this

Comment: Side comment: ```sumFirstAndLastDigit``` does not seem like a good name fpr a method to 'find the length of a given number'.   Likewise, summing the first and last digits does not seem to me to require first knowing its length.

Comment: *"In this case with the number 12321 the answer should be 6 but it prints 0."* You mean 5, right? 12321, 1232, 123, 12, and 1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're telling it to loop while `instanceNumber <= 0`. The "test" in a `for` loop is a "keep going" test, not a termination test. The loop continues as long as the test is *true*.

From your description, you want `instanceNumber > 0`.

Also note [Avinash Gupta's point](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56892884/157247) that with your current code, you'll undercount by one. I'd address that by using a completely different loop:

```
int numberLength = 0;
int instanceNumber = number;
while (instanceNumber > 0) {
    ++numberLength;
    instanceNumber /= 10;
}
```

That's nice and unambiguous: If `instanceNumber > 0`, it increments `numberLength`, then divides by 10 and tries again.

Comment: it actually will

Comment: It will always give lenght -1

Comment: again, you are right. Code above is lacking +1 change

Answer (score 2):

This will print the correct output

```
public static void sumFirstAndLastDigit(int number) {
    int numberLength = 0;
    int instanceNumber = number;
    for(int i = 0; instanceNumber > 0; i++) {
         instanceNumber /= 10;
         numberLength = i;   
     }
     System.out.println("Number length = " + (numberLength + 1));

    }
```

Comment: This is no different from what @T.J. Crowder advising

Comment: It has. See in the syout. I have added +1 in the numberLength.

Comment: If you don't add +1, you will always get count one short what is expected.

Comment: `("Number length = " + numberLength+1)` it's funny, but doing so you'll always get 1 concatenated at the end, it can be fixed with ``("Number length = " + (numberLength+1))``

Comment: I am afraid but your understanding is wrong here. Number will get appended after performing the addition operation.

Comment: my understanding isn't wrong, and proven by real test)

Comment: Let's hope that author will actually see this one and accept it. You've got vote from me. Nice catch:-)

Comment: Your right I just fixed it later though you do need the I loop variable to star at one

Comment: *"It has. See in the syout. I have added +1 in the numberLength."* This is why code dumps are not *useful* answers. Always say *what* you did, and *why*.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will be much more comprehensive if you use while loop for your algorithm.

```
public static void sumFirstAndLastDigit(int number) {
    int numberLength = 0;
    int instanceNumber = number;
    while(instanceNumber != 0) {
        instanceNumber /= 10;
        numberLength += 1;
    }
    System.out.println("Number length = " + numberLength);
    // to find length of number loop division by 10
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider even more sophisticated solution:

```
public static void sumFirstAndLastDigit(int number) {
    int numberLength = (int) (Math.log10(number) + 1);
    System.out.println("Number length = " + numberLength);
}
```

> Taken from [Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/java-number-of-digits-in-int)